# Looking for a fullscreen jQuery slider for HTML content

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I know there are hundreds of jquery sliders out there, but that is what makes it difficult to find one for a specific situation.

I need one similar to [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html) but for HTML content, not only images. So what I need is:

- Optimized for full screen
- Support fot HTML content
- The slide animation in [this example of Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html)

My plan is to use it with AJAX to load wordpress content, so if it has AJAX requests built in, even better.

Comment: Do you mean something like http://www.maxicodesign.co.uk/dev/ ?

Comment: Yes, kinda like that. Also similar to http://www.ultranoir.com/en/#!/home/

Comment: I will use it to see Wordpress posts, so each post will be loaded with AJAX and then animated like this.

Answer (score 5):

I created Superslides ([demo](http://nicinabox.github.com/superslides/)) for this purpose. It's designed to take any kind of content, and doesn't force a specific markup structure. I don't think you'll be able to append slides after it's been initialized though. However, you could load all the slides with AJAX, then initialize it.

Comment: Hell yes, this is an absolutely awesome plugin Nic.  Great work!

Comment: @nic-aitch : Does it work with AngularJS (precisely ng-repeat)?
Sorry to bug you after couple of years, I have found Superslides quite useful, but I am unable to make it work with AngularJS unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, it's been quite a while since I've touched it and I've only barely worked with Angular in production. Presumably you should be able to build the template with any lib and initialize superslides after.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

1. http://css-tricks.com/3412-anythingslider-jquery-plugin/
2. http://brenelz.com/blog/build-a-content-slider-with-jquery/
3. http://codecanyon.net/item/fss-full-screen-sliding-website-plugin/159103?ref=lydian&clickthrough_id=27905824&redirect_back=true

They are not exactly like Supersized but you can modify them.

Answer (score 1):

http://nicinabox.github.com/superslides/

Comment: Can you write a bit more about it?

Comment: Answers with just a link are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I like flexslider http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ its responsive, so would probably work well for full screen after a couple tweaks